# Error installing Ruby 2.0 using RVM on OS X Snow Leopard

Tags: ruby, makefile, rvm, ruby-2.0

I'm trying to install Ruby 2.0 using RVM on my Macbook running Snow Leopard.
RVM Version - 1.18.18
XCode Version - 4.0.2
GCC Version - 4.2.1

When I run `rvm install 2.0.0`, it fails with

```
Error running 'make -j4',
please read /Users/membLoper/.rvm/log/ruby-2.0.0-p0/make.log
```

And the make.log fails with 'Bus Error'. Complete log here https://gist.github.com/anonymous/1cacd89ee0d4fb2be3e2

I suspect its something to do with my gcc but cannot figure out what exactly. I've tried setting the readline to brew installed location, setting the gcc to Clang and still run into this error. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: have a look at this post: http://www.moncefbelyamani.com/how-to-install-xcode-homebrew-git-rvm-ruby-on-mac/

Comment: A good source but I've more or less covered every step in there. I have a working ruby 1.9.3 environment setup using very similar steps to those and can even reinstall ruby 1.9.3 without issues. 

The problem occurs only when I try to install ruby 2.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is because of the old Xcode, try compiling using `CC=gcc-4.2` - but it does not have to work, if that fails try to update Xcode or install Command Line Tools for Xcode

Comment: I was hunting like a mad dog for this solution.. **Superb** - Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me:

```
rvm install 2.0.0 --autolibs=2 --with-gcc=clang
```

Comment: Hmm, I did try the same and it did not work. I guess your XCode is higher version than mine and accommodated Ruby 2.0 compilation.

Comment: I did update all the things before trying to install the official release of 2.0.  I believe that installing the 2 release candidates involved jumping through a different set of hoops that I thought I'd written down but apparently had not.